# IntelliJ 2016.3 high CPU usage spikes

Tags: intellij-idea

A few days ago I've upgraded to IntelliJ ultimate 2016.3 and my CPU usage spikes to 50-80% when editing files, even writing a character. I'm running the 64bit .exe on Windows 10 Pro. I also tried increasing the custom vm options and I currently have this:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Another thing I tried was the `Invalidate Caches` option but it doesn't help. The IDE is basically unusable like this as it freezes my notebook. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Edit: I also tried IntelliJ 2016.2.5 but with the same issue. For the record previously I had 2016.2 with no problems.

### Final edit:

I have large-ish source files on the project I'm working (1k+ and more) and the IDE seems to be too bloated to be able to handle them.
What I tried:

- Adding more RAM (1-2GB or more)
- Disabling almost all inspections
- Disabling every plugin I don't use
- Excluding everything except the sources from the `Project Structure`
- [Disabling autosave](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207054215-Disabling-autosave).

Nothing helped too much. Searching online I found others with the same problem - basically that the IDE is unusable on large (1K or more) source files. This doesn't seem to be a bug so it's useless to report it. It forced me to move to eclipse which never had any high CPU issues on my machine.

**To the reader**: If you're in this situation spare yourself a couple of hours or more of useless tweaking and know there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Is windows 10 a new addition as well?

Comment: Did you report the issue to jet-brains ?

Comment: Do you have antivirus running on the system ? If so, is it possible that you had excluded the previous version of Intellij from antivirus 'on-access-scanner' and did not do so for v 2016.3 (since that would have new folders etc) ?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal I only have what windows provided which is Windows Defender. I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to check if you see the high CPU usage with a new project? Does the `idea.log` (`Help -> Show log in explorer`) show anything when this happens?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev No.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using 2016.3 for a while now and have not noticed the CPU spikes (albeit, I am on OSX so this may not mean much).

First, I would recommend looking at the idea.log file (`Help -> Show log in explorer`) as the first place for anything obvious (such as a rogue plugin). Ideally, you'd tail the log file while typing in the editor and see what comes up in the log file.

Secondly, confirm if the problem is reproducible in a new project. If it is, then move on to the next step which is to capture a CPU Snapshot when the problem happens for a couple of minutes and creating a new issue at **[Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/)**. To capture a new CPU snapshot refer the official documentation "**[Reporting Performance Problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems)**". Steps summarized below:

---

### Step 1 : If using community edition, add YourKit profiler lib

(Skip if using ultimate edition)

> IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm Community Editions do not include a YourKit
>   profiler agent, because the YourKit agent library is not open-source.
>   To take a CPU or memory snapshot with the Community Edition, you can
>   download an evaluation version of YourKit Java Profiler, copy the
>   yjpagent library to the IDE bin directory, add it to the .vmoptions as
>   described above, and connect to the running IDE instance from the
>   standalone YourKit Profiler UI.

---

### Step 2 : Enable the profile agent

#### Step TL;DR

`Help | Edit Custom VM Options` and add, at the end of the file, `-agentlib:yjpagent64=delay=10000` if using 64 bit jvm or `-agentlib:yjpagent=delay=10000` if using 32 bit

#### Details

[image]

---

### Step 3 : Capture CPU Snapshot

[image]

Comment: YourKit agent library has BSD license.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. How it is now the IDE is useless, I'll switch back to eclipse which never has any issues.

Comment: @Daniel `I'll switch back to eclipse which never has any issues` Nice joke

Comment: @SvetlinZarev If I never had any issues with eclipse then what I said holds. Why comment when you contribute nothing to this thread?

Comment: "Enable the profile agent" after setting this option, Idea (2017.2.1) stopped starting

Answer (score 0):

I have found that disabling Javascript "Unused JavaScript / Action Script local symbol" inspection has solved this issue for me in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 (had same problems in 2016.2). You can search for this setting in the settings pane.

I have submitted a ticket here -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173800

Also checkout the suggestion here for JavaScript Inspections ( -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16757